# How to get sum of firestore document values using fold? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: record,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          ..........

          ..........
        final totalIncome =
            snapshot.data?.docs.fold<double>(0, (previousValue, element) {
          return previousValue + (element['incomeAmount'] ?? 0.0);
        }) as double;

     ...........
     ...........
```

This works if a field exists. If there is no field in firestore this gives an error field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

How can I make it work something like

> element?['incomeAmount']

or if there is no field return 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function to get the **totalAmount**. It can be look like this

```dart
  int? getTotal(List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>> snapData) {
   if(mounted){
     return snapData.fold<int>(
      0,
      (prev, current) =>
          prev +
          (Model.fromJson(current.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)
              .amount));
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Finally, you can call **getTotal** wherever you want.

```dart
 Text(getTotal(snapshot.data!.docs).toString()),
```

[**You can see this GIF to check if it is correct or wrong**](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31488481/180055774-5442122f-562d-4027-b773-aa80ec71801b.gif)