# Calculate total of integer values in every document firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Database]

I need to calculate the total of "number" values in every document in the "Requests" collection.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: You can check this approach! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71011510/how-to-get-sum-of-firestore-document-values-using-fold-flutter/73056582#73056582

Comment: Can this collection grow a lot? If so, it's better to implement a more efficient way to do this, you could use cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

this `Future` method will calculate it:

```
    Future<int> calculateIt() async {
    final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Requests").get();
    int sum = 0;
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) {
      String numberField  = (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["number"] as String;
      sum += int.parse(numberField);
    });  
     return sum;
     }
```

note that the number field is a `String` so you will need to parse it to an `int` to make a +` operation over it.